# Successor to pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Is there a successor to [pygame](http://www.pygame.org)? The latest version (1.9.1) was released on 2009-08-06 according to [the website](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml).

I am thinking of using it to develop a home project but if it deprecated and there is a known successor, I may prefer to use that.

Comment: All the action happens on bitbucket. It's just the official homepage that is kind of deprecated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyGame is an excellent library and I would recommend you use it, especially if you wish to program games. The website is not always that regularly updated. But there are latest versions for most recent python releases. Try https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads